# Optimize informix update

Tags: sql, informix

I have a bash script that will update a table based on a file.  The way I have it it opens and closes for every line in the file and would like to understand how to open, perform all the updates, and then close. It is fine for a few updates but if it ever requires more than a few hundred could be really taxing on the system.

```
    #!/bin/bash

    file=/export/home/dncs/tmp/file.csv
    dateFormat=$(date +"%m-%d-%y-%T")
    LOGFILE=/export/home/dncs/tmp/Log_${dateFormat}.log

    echo "${dateFormat} : Starting work" >> $LOGFILE 2>&1

    while IFS="," read mac loc; do
      if [[ "$mac" =~ ^([0-9a-fA-F]{2}:){5}[0-9a-fA-F]{2}$ ]]; then


    dbaccess thedb <<EndOfUpdate >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
    UPDATE profile
    SET local_code= '$loc'
    WHERE mac_address = '$mac';
    EndOfUpdate
      else
    echo "Error: $mac not valid format" >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
    fi
    IIH -i $mac >> $LOGFILE 2>&1


    done <"$file"
```

Source File.

```
12:BF:20:04:BB:30,POR-4
12:BF:21:1C:02:B1,POR-10
12:BF:20:04:72:FD,POR-4
12:BF:20:01:5B:4F,POR-10
12:BF:20:C2:71:42,POR-7
```

Comment: What's the `IIH -i $mac` doing?  Does that need to be done synchronously with the individual updates?  So the sequence needs to be 'update; run IIH` for each MAC address?

Comment: no it can run after the full update is done

Comment: Could you provide say 2 lines of good data and 1 of bad for illustrative purposes?  Edit the question to add it — you can format it there.

Comment: There is no bad it just takes longer to churn through a list of say 1000 than wanted. I know opening and closing is not ideal line by line.

Comment: So the 'Error: $mac not valid format' message is for decoration, and never used?  It certainly makes life easier.

Comment: its just a check so it does not attempt to send an update to a ill formed mac.

Answer (score 1):

This is more or less what I'd do:

```
#!/bin/bash

fmt_date() { date +"%Y-%m-%d.%T"; }

file=/export/home/dncs/tmp/file.csv
dateFormat=$(fmt_date)
LOGFILE="/export/home/dncs/tmp/Log_${dateFormat}.log"

exec >> $LOGFILE 2>&1

echo "${dateFormat} : Starting work"

valid_mac='/^\(\([0-9a-fA-F]\{2\}:\)\{5\}[0-9a-fA-F]\{2\}\),\([^,]*\)$/'
update_stmt="UPDATE profile SET local_code = '\3' WHERE mac_address = '\1';"

sed -n -e "$valid_mac s//$update_stmt/p" "$file" |
dbaccess thedb -

sed -n -e "$valid_mac d; s/.*/Error: invalid format: &/p" "$file"

sed -n -e "$valid_mac s//IIH -i \1/p" "$file" | sh

echo "$(fmt_date) : Finished work"
```

I changed the date format to a variant of ISO 8601; it is easier to parse.  You can stick with your Y2K-non-compliant US-ish format if you prefer.  The `exec` line arranges for standard output and standard error from here onwards to go to the log file.  The `sed` command all use the same structure, and all use the same pattern match stored in a variable.  This makes consistency easier.  The first `sed` script converts the data into UPDATE statements (which are fed to `dbaccess`).  The second script identifies invalid MAC addresses; it deletes valid ones and maps the invalid lines into error messages.  The third script ignores invalid MAC addresses but generates a `IIH` command for each valid one.  The script records an end time — it will allow you to assess how long the processing takes.  Again, repetition is avoided by creating and using the `fmt_date` function.

Be cautious about testing this.  I had a file `data` containing:

```
87:36:E6:5E:AC:41,loc-OYNK
B2:4D:65:70:32:26,loc-DQLO
ZD:D9:BA:34:FD:97,loc-PLBI
04:EB:71:0D:29:D0,loc-LMEE
DA:67:53:4B:EC:C4,loc-SFUU
```

I replaced the `dbaccess` with `cat`, and the `sh` with `cat`.  The log file I relocated to the current directory — leading to:

```
#!/bin/bash

fmt_date() { date +"%Y-%m-%d.%T"; }

#file=/export/home/dncs/tmp/file.csv
file=data
dateFormat=$(fmt_date)
#LOGFILE="/export/home/dncs/tmp/Log_${dateFormat}.log"
LOGFILE="Log-${dateFormat}.log"

exec >> $LOGFILE 2>&1

echo "${dateFormat} : Starting work"

valid_mac='/^\(\([0-9a-fA-F]\{2\}:\)\{5\}[0-9a-fA-F]\{2\}\),\([^,]*\)$/'
update_stmt="UPDATE profile SET local_code = '\3' WHERE mac_address = '\1';"

sed -n -e "$valid_mac s//$update_stmt/p" "$file" |
cat
#dbaccess thedb -

sed -n -e "$valid_mac d; s/.*/Error: invalid format: &/p" "$file"

#sed -n -e "$valid_mac s//IIH -i \1/p" "$file" | sh
sed -n -e "$valid_mac s//IIH -i \1/p" "$file" | cat

echo "$(fmt_date) : Finished work"
```

After I ran it, the log file contained:

```
2017-04-27.14:58:20 : Starting work
UPDATE profile SET local_code = 'loc-OYNK' WHERE mac_address = '87:36:E6:5E:AC:41';
UPDATE profile SET local_code = 'loc-DQLO' WHERE mac_address = 'B2:4D:65:70:32:26';
UPDATE profile SET local_code = 'loc-LMEE' WHERE mac_address = '04:EB:71:0D:29:D0';
UPDATE profile SET local_code = 'loc-SFUU' WHERE mac_address = 'DA:67:53:4B:EC:C4';
Error: invalid format: ZD:D9:BA:34:FD:97,loc-PLBI
IIH -i 87:36:E6:5E:AC:41
IIH -i B2:4D:65:70:32:26
IIH -i 04:EB:71:0D:29:D0
IIH -i DA:67:53:4B:EC:C4
2017-04-27.14:58:20 : Finished work
```

The UPDATE statements would have gone to DB-Access.  The bogus MAC address was identified.  The correct `IIH` commands would have been run.

Note that piping the output into `sh` requires confidence that the data you generate (the `IIH` commands) will be clean.